# Fix "Permission Denied" when copying files

Tags: macos, usb, partition, permission

Whenever I try to copy all the content of a usb to my Mac partition it says `Permission Denied`

The command I am using is

`cp -R /dev/disk1 /dev/disk0s3`

My error message is:

`/dev/disk0s3: permission denied.`

I have tried to set myself to super and still didn't work, as well I have all write/read permissions on the hard drive.

Is there a way I can buffer the copy by coping all the files to a folder then partition. I need all the contents of the usb to be copied and I believe there are hidden files and partitions on the usb that need to be copied. (is it a recovery usb I want to put on the recovery partition i created and no i cannot just create one, this recovery contents important files of mine)

Comment: Why are you using the raw device names - cp works off the mounted disc system

Comment: @Mark because I would like to copy **everything** off of the usb stick and not just the files show in finder

Comment: cp will copy all files if used on the filesystem

Answer (score 3):

You can't use filesystem commands (`cp`, `mv`, `ls`, etc.) on devices (`/dev/*`).

If you want to copy everything, bit-for-bit, from volume to volume, you'll need an app like [Super Duper](http://www.shirt-pocket.com/SuperDuper/) or [Carbon Copy Cloner](http://www.bombich.com/).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to copy all *files* including hidden files that will not show up in the Finder use

```
cp -r /Volumes/foo bar
```

Of course you can replace `bar` with `/Volumes/bar` to copy from one disk to another. You may run into problems fixier destination filesystem is not capable of everything used in the source. (For example when copying from HFSX to (j)HFS+ or from HFS+ to FAT32.)

In case you really need to image the full device use

```
dd if=/dev/disk1 of=destination.img
```

Replace the `/dev/disk1` with the actual device you want to copy from. Replace `destination.img` with a filename and path of choice or with another real device. You likely will need to do this as `root` so double check if your source and especially destination are correct to prevent overwriting the wrong disk.

Other commands that may come in handy for this include `rsync(1)` and `ditto(1)`.

Comment: I get `permission denied` using `cp -r /Volumes/foo bar` (Of course with my actual folders names).